# Blank Cells in the middle of my xlDown

Tags: vba

I have the code below:

```
Worksheets("L.NAM.M").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    **Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select**
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("NewForecast").Select
    Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

in the bald line I would like to find the last row with data, but if I have blank cells in the middle, it will not copy what is after the blank cells. I want to copy everything, even the blank cells. has data 
So If in the range A2:A100, A41 is blank, I want it keep going until the last data then copy everything even the A41.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a little revision of your code to stick to what it actually does and you request:

```
Worksheets("L.NAM.M").Select
Cells.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Copy
Sheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
```

but

- finding "forecast_quarter" seems of no use, since you don't use that cell at all
- there still are some Select/Activate that ought to be avoided

  this can be done as long you tell us about the former point

---

**edit** after some thoughts of what you might actually want to do

should you ever want to:

- copy cells from "L.NAM.M" worksheet starting from below the one with "forecast_quarter" down to the last not empty one in the same column
- paste it to first not empty cell in column "K" of worksheet "NewForecast"

then try this:

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("L.NAM.M")
        With .Cells.Find(What:="forecast_quarter", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a great advice! The second piece is doing exactly what I wanted.
Thank you very very much!